How can you find the canonical, axis-aligned basis of a quadric?
I would like to know how to find the canonical, axis-aligned system of coordinates for a quadric, given the coefficients describing this quadric. I found this paper describing how to achieve this, see screenshots below. However, I can not figure out how to find the translation vector to center the quadric at the origin.
Any insights would be appreciated!



Writing $x$, $y$, $z$ for $p_x$, $p_y$, $p_z$ ... Let $f_x$, $f_y$, $f_z$ be the corresponding partial derivatives of $f$. The center of the quadric (when it exists) is the solution to the linear system $f_x=f_y=f_z=0$.

@Blue In my project, I am dealing with a parabolic cylinder. This type of quadric does not have a center I believe.

"I am dealing with a parabolic cylinder. This type of quadric does not have a center I believe." Correct. So, finding "the translation vector to center to quadric at the origin" is problematic. Hmmm ... On closer reading, I see that the passage is suggesting centering the quadric along the corresponding axis for a given non-zero squared term, to eliminate the associated linear term. This is good ol' complete-the-square stuff: Post-rotation, the quadric has the form $ax^2+by^2+cz^2+2dx+2ey+2fz+g$. For, say, $a\neq0$, we have $a(x+d/a)^2+by^2+cz^2+2ey+2fz+g-d^2/a$; no linear $x$ term.
